# There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Trying to migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 5.0 using this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) provided by Microsoft.

Installed SDK 5.0.100-rc.1 with runtimes. Updated project as guide says and still getting following error:

```
There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'
```

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <UserSecretsId>*****</UserSecretsId>
    </PropertyGroup>
...
```

Cant find anything asociated with this error. I have no idea where to search for more info.

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: And which Visual Studio are you running?  It should be the latest Preview edition.

Comment: The error message seems to be publish error,did you make this error when you publish to IIS?If so,it seems to be a [know issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24388) on github,please check and you could update to the latest version of .net 5.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes it is latest preview version. 16.8.0 Preview 3.0

Comment: Do you have a *global.json* file ?

Comment: @aguafrommars Yes.

   {
     "sdk": {
       "version": "5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10"
     }
   }

Comment: I am seeing the same issue.  Was meticulous in following the guide; double-checked all NuGet packages.  I am also on VS Pro Version 16.8.0 Preview 3.0, with dotnet.exe 5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10 and Build Engine version 16.8.0-preview-20451-02+51a1071f8

Comment: what `dotnet --list-sdks` returns ? is 5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10 present ?

Comment: Yes, it is the final one. 

 ```2.1.509 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

3.1.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

3.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

3.1.300-preview-015048 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

3.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]```  I do not think it is a publishing error, as I get it when I do `dotnet build`.

Comment: @aguafrommars yes, 5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk] is present

Comment: Do you have a package reference to *Microsoft.AspNetCore.App* in your projects ?

Comment: I do not have a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.

Comment: Do you update blazor wasm packages references to the latest version ?

Comment: Yes, I did, just as it directs in the guide linked above.

Comment: Did you try to delete *obj*, *bin* and *.vs* folders ?

Comment: Just did; no change.

Comment: Same as @PatrickSzalapski

Comment: Do you by any chance have a project reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server` in your client project?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I finally made it work.

I did everything that [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) said, except for the project file which I changed to this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>*****</UserSecretsId>
    <UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

But I have no idea if it is correct when [official upgrade guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) says to use:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
```

instead of:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

Comment: After changing my Project file as you say, and adding the `UseBlazorWebAssembly` as true, my client project builds, but then when I run its Server project, I get `Application startup exception: System.TypeLoadException: Method 'FilterDiagnostic' in type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilationOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.`

Comment: I don't see anything in the [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.1-5.0) about `FilterDiagnostic` or `UseEndpoints`.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I am using Blazor Server so I have only one project in my solution. No idea how to help you. Try to focus on Richards answer below.

Comment: Yep - same for me.

Comment: ditto=>same for me

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue and finally got it working. Here's how.

In my case, the error wasn't the result of the **Blazor project** itself, but a **referenced project** in the same solution. The referenced project targets .net standard 2.1, which should be fine in itself; however, it also had some NuGet packages installed which might conflict with Blazor dependencies: (Microsoft.Extensions.*).

```
Solution
- Project A (.net standard 2.1 - Class library)
  - Dependencies
    - Packages
      - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (<-- example dependency)
- Project B (.net 5 - Blazor webassembly)
  - Dependencies
    - Projects
      - Project A (<-- caused the error, presumably because of the above dependency)
```

The [blog post about .net 5 rc](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-1/) mentions all Microsoft.Extensions.* packages in a **Blazor project** should be updated to 5.0.0-rc.1.*.

Was able to resolve the issue by removing the project dependency (which I didn't need in the first place, but accidentally got placed there).

What I don't understand is why a 'dotnet build' doesn't give an understandable error message about a conflict instead of this vague message about the runtime identifier mentioning the **Blazor project**.

Hope this will help others as well.

Comment: Which extensions specifically? The Extensions used by Blazor Client are very different from the Extensions used by server-side ASP.NET Core. There shouldn't be any problems if ProjectA used the *abstractions* packages.

Comment: BTW .NET 5 doesn't use .NET Standard anymore to share code cross-platform. The .NET 5 target (`net5.0`)*is* the cross-platform target, with `net5.0-ios14.0` being the specific runtime. .NET Standard 2.1 is supported for compatibility but no longer used as *the* cross-platform target

Comment: I updated all four projects in my solution to `net5.0` but still get the same error. In your example, you thought that package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json was conflicting.  Any idea how I might try to find what indirect dependencies of mine might be conflicting?

Comment: Honestly, not really. Guess I'd just try the old fashioned way by trial and error. (Create a new (empty) project with the same dependencies and reference that project from your blazor project. Then remove the dependencies one by one until the build succeeds.

Comment: I was trying to use Blazor WASM + gRPC server and when I added the gRPC service on Blazor project, I had this issue. To resolve this I follow this answer and remove the duplicated dependencies from the projects (Grpc.AspNetCore, added automatically on Blazor project), and everything worked.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I had referenced a project that was referencing Data layer classes and there for was not safe for Blazor Client side or 'browser-wasm'.

After I removed the reference from Client solution > Dependencies > Projects
My solution compiled.

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue and asked Microsoft about that under this post:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27738

You need to update your projects to use below SDK's;

```
Client - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly
Server - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web
Shared - Microsoft.NET.Sdk
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem after I updated nuget packages and added incorrect package to incorrect project.
I had a librabry **Project.Application.csproj** with:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

in this project I had package:

```
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="10.4.0" />
```

I accidently added additional package:

```
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="10.4.0" />
```

and then my code broke.

It seems **FluentValidation.AspNetCore** is not compatible with Blazor Client Project - **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly** which reference the librabry **Project.Application.csproj** so be aware of all projects referenced in your Blazor project so they don't contain incompatible packages.

Comment: I had done the same thing. Tryin to upgrade my project with FluentValidation as I was using Blazored.FluentValidation and it was no longer compatible with the latest MC framework/runtime. Ending up installing FluentValidation.AspNetCore which was not the correct one.

Comment: I got this after adding some serilog pakages, removing some of the older ones solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help, In my case, I have to followup steps mentioned by @Kasta and official guide.

I make sure that below SDK changes are in place,Thank you @OzanYasinDogan for mentioning this helps.

- Client - `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly`
- Server - `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`
- Shared - `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`

In my case, I had to

- Remove the `<RuntimeIdentifier>browser-wasm</RuntimeIdentifier>` and
  `<UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>`.
  [Mentioned here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-7/#upgrade-existing-blazor-webassembly-projects)
- Remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.BuildServer` which was version 3.xx.xx causing conflicts from `Blazor.Client` Project file.

Answer (score 2):

In a NET 6.0 Blazor app, I managed to get this error by accidently adding these to my Shared project instead of the API project - corrected and problem went away.

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" PrivateAssets="all" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a different error message "The type or namespace name 'ApplicationPartAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

In my case I had a shared helper class library that I had started to build generic data api repositories into using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0 which was referenced in my Blazor project using the newly released .Net 5.

To resolve this, I had to separate the shared class project moving the generic data api elements to a new project which removed the link between .Net 5 Blazor and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The error gone after comment out reference to the following packages in a project refered by BlazorWASM app,

```xml
<!--<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="10.3.6" />-->
        <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.1" />-->
        <!--<PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.14.0" />-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issu and I resolve it by using:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AssemblyName>$(AssemblyName.Replace(' ', '_'))</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Instead of:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <AssemblyName>$(AssemblyName.Replace(' ', '_'))</AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup> -->

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent two hours messing around with a really basic setup where I'd extracted the default Blazor pages to a separate Razor Component Library assembly - trying to isolate dependencies, up and down-versioning nugets, changing project settings, removing the bin and obj folders...

**I finally fixed it by updating my VS 2022 to 17.5.1**

I'm not sure why that's worked, but is has :/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in a way Richard described:

1. Cleaned up references to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration,... packages version 3.2 in all solution projects referenced by server and client
2. Updated .Server project
3. Updated .Client project.
   Kept  element at target framework section and it worked

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and discovered the cause to be

```xml
    <UseAppHost>true</UseAppHost>
```

which was used in a common `Directory.Build.props`

By setting this back to false I no longer get the missing `browser-wasm` error.