# Client Side Blazor throwing 500.31

Tags: blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

On last Thursday everything was running fine with my client side Blazor app. Then today I started to get two new errors.

`There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'`

At first this issue didn't seem to be a problem because everthing still compiled. However, when I run the app I get the below error:

`HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies`

If you follow the link on the page it basically says that you do not have the runtime installed.

I had .Net 5 preview 8 installed, so I upgraded to .Net 5 rc 1 and the issues still remains. Has anyone seen this before?

Also, when the app builds nothing is placed into the debug folder.

Thank you,
Travis Pettry

Comment: There was an identical question just yesterday. Do you have a `global.json` targeting an older runtime version perhaps? Older .NET 5 runtimes or SDKs still installed? You can try [removing olderr .NET Core preview verrsions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-windows) or creating a new `global.json` in your project folder

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no I do not. I also, uninstalled the preview .Net 5 before updating. I get the same issue if I create a new Blazor project.

Comment: If you have a  `global.json` in a parent folder or the disk's root it will override the current SDK. Try `dotnet new globaljson` in you project's root to create a new `global.json`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added one, bu tit had no effect. I have added the contents of the global.json {
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10"
  }
}

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oddly visual studio acts like I haven't installed any nuget packages into the project either.

Comment: When I run dotnet --info I see that I have two .net 5 installed 1)  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0-preview.8.20407.11
 2) Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0-rc.1.20451.14, but the control panel shows that I only have one installed

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue `(There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm')` and finally got it working.

In my case, the error wasn't the result of the **Blazor project** itself, but a **referenced project** in the same solution.

Check the [related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993294/there-was-no-runtime-pack-for-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-available-for-the-specifi/64023951#64023951) for the answer provided there.

Comment: That answer is a bit incomplete. Which extensions specifically? The client and server runtimes are different, requiring different implementations, so using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` would be expected to fail but `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` probably shouldn't fail

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Just had the same issue referencing .NET 6 Class Library in .NET 6 Web Assembly app. The solution was to remove reference to Serilog.AspNetCore Nuget package from the library.

Comment: @Anonymous that package is used to configure logging on an ASP.NET Core web app, not Blazor WASM. In a Blazor WASM there's nowhere to log except the browser console or sending logs to some server. There are [different Serilog packages for Blazor WASM logging](https://nblumhardt.com/2019/11/serilog-blazor/). Besides, if you want to create a reusable library you shouldn't force developers to use a specific logging library or configuration. The library should depend only on `ILogger<>` which is part of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstraction`