# Problem with Client reference 'There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm''

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I am trying to make a shared class library in .NET 5 with a .proto file in it and 3 dependencies:

- Google.protobuf
- Grpc.Aspnetcore
- Grpc.Tools

When I add a project reference from the server project there is no problem whatsoever. I know this for sure because I first built the project without the shared folder and everything was working as it should. When I made the shared project and only changed the server project, it still worked perfectly.

However, as soon as I added a reference from the Client project to the shared project an error message appeared on the build(I have also tried adding a service reference, with the same error occurring):

> `There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'`

This issue was mentioned in this question: *["There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993294/there-was-no-runtime-pack-for-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-available-for-the-specifi/64023798#64023798)*

However one of the solutions is removing the dependency but that's not possible in my case.

The other solution says I should make some changes in the .csproj file of the client. But when I do this, the solution **does build**, but it will not load because it all of the sudden can't find the `Blazor.WebAssembly.js` file.

Has anyone had the same problem or knows what it could be? Don't hesitate to ask any question for extra information!

Comment: Is this question still open or did you find a solution?

Comment: I still did not find a solution, my current workaround is to have the shared files saved in both projects which is not desireable ofcourse.

Comment: Can you please update your question and provide more information which Grpc/protobuf dependencies you have in each project?