# OpenIdConnect .Net 5.0 blazor webassembly gives error on clean: no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

If I use Nuget "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="5.0.0"
with .Net 5.0 blazor webassembly I get the following error on clean: NETSDK1082 There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

I created a brand new blazor webassembly .Net 5.0 project as in the below project file. The issue occurs when I include an openidconnect reference, but disappears if I delete that reference.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I have tried starting a new blazor webassembly .Net 5.0 project and can reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your project file to below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>browser-wasm</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If it doesn't work,you can see more details in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993294/there-was-no-runtime-pack-for-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-available-for-the-specifi).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that thread, but it still doesn't work. I'm also a bit reluctant to take a step backward from the latest Microsoft recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not related to OpenIddict and is caused by the fact you're trying to reference a package - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` - that you're not supposed to use on Blazor.

It's a pure server-side package that CAN'T work on Blazor, which has its own OIDC authentication stack: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/