# Logout page not found on logout in Blazor App in Static Web App

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app, microsoft-entra-id

With Visual Studio I have created a Blazor Webassembly App with c# version 7.
I used the new project wizard and I added support for Microsoft Identity platform.

I got created the standard app from the template with the ability to log in and out using Microsoft Accounts.

Everything works in localhost, but when I deploy the project to Azure Static Web Apps, I have an issue on logout.

When I hit the logout button I'm asked:

"Which account do you want to sign out of?"

and then I'm redirected to:

https://xxxxxxxxx.westeurope.4.azurestaticapps.net/authentication/logout-callback?state=xxxxx

That page is returning  404: Not Found

If I do the same thing from localhost I'm sendt to
https://localhost:7032/authentication/logout-callback?state=5ea09de5-0901-4a63-b724-dc78b5b46bf0
And then finally to
https://localhost:7032/authentication/logged-out

I can't figure out if this is caused by settings in Azure or by the app and I'm not sure what part of my code I should show you.

/authentication/logout-callback
/authentication/logged-out

Are added to Redirect URIs in Azure.

If I deploy the app to a local folder I get this appsettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "f0e0c409-31a3-4d18-9c72-698f13d6c4af",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/skovstedconsulting.dk",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}
```

This is web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When user hits logout, NavigateToLogout is executed with the parameter "authentication/logout"

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginLogOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    public void BeginLogOut()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");
    }
}
```

That would be routed to the page Authentication.razor

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }
}
```

Somewhere in the process the user is redirected to authentication/logout-callback, and that would again be Authentication.razor, but why is that not found?

I don't know if it's related, but in App.razor this code is supposed to handle cases of not found. It's working in localhost, but when deployed to Static Web App it just returns 404.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
        ...
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
        ...
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Any hints are very much appreciated.

BR Kresten

Comment: Do you have a LoginDisplay.razor page? Look at the href in there.

Comment: Sure, I'll include it in the question

Comment: The user is redirected to authentication/logout-callback, and that routes to  Authentication.razor. Why is that not found?

Comment: If you're using Microsoft Identity Platform then your href should be MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut. This is not an actual file, by default, and is located in the package Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI. Looks like you're using a custom logout view.

Comment: Go to nuget and include the packages Microsoft.Idendity.Web and Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI.

Comment: Doing so, gives me the error: "There is no runtime pack availabel for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App Blazor WASM"
It goes away, if I change the project file to from <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly"> to <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> as according to this issuehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993294/there-was-no-runtime-pack-for-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-available-for-the-specifi. Now the project compiles, but the page won't load when I run the project.

Comment: Can you please share your GitHub repo?

Comment: Please refer [GitHub](https://github.com/anthonychu/blazor-auth-static-web-apps/tree/main/sample/app) which explains the Authentication for Blazor WASM Azure Static WebApp.